# Get file name from Uri in Android

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I have an Uri build using below code

```
final Uri fileUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, docId);
```

that contains value:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%Sample/document/primary%Sample%2FMedia%2F.Hide%2FScreenshot_1615959401.png/children

Below is my code to access the name and mime type of file:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(fileUri, new String[]{DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE}, null, null, null);
try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
          //Here cursor.moveToFirst() returns false
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**I want to access the name of file like Screenshot_1615959401.png, mime type file like image/png from above Uri but cursor.moveToFirst() returns 0. Why record is not found even Uri is valid. Because I try to use this Uri to load image and ImageView is displaying the image correctly using above Uri.**

*Any Help would be highly appreciated as I spent lots of time googling and read on SO but didn't find any solution or root cause of it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Below is my code to access the name and mime type of file:

That `Uri` is not for a document. It is for the roster of child documents for a document tree, where the tree is identified by `docId`. `childDocumentsUri` is the core of the name of the method that you are calling.

> Why record is not found even Uri is valid

It is not valid for your desired action.

If you wish to build a `Uri` for a document, given a document ID and a tree, [use `buildDocumentUriUsingTree()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#buildDocumentUriUsingTree(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)), not `buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint, you saved me. I checked that method but not sure why I did not get any idea. Thank you again.